# Why do Arduinos ship w/ 16MHz crystal instead of 20MHz?

Tags: arduino, crystal, clock-speed

Why do Arduino boards ship w/ 16MHz crystal instead of 20MHz? They are spec'ed for operating at 20MHz, after all.

I guess there are a few advantages to running more slowly (lower power consumption, longer life), but I must be missing something.

Comment: This was also asked in the old Arduino Forum: http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1240016311

Comment: Note that this 25% application speed gap can be gained many times over with proper programming. I try to stay away from any IC's extreme limits, though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd buy into the answer on the Arduino Forum:

> The original ATmega8 Arduino ran at 16MHz, which was the top rated
>   clock speed for the ATmega8 cpu used. When "upgraded" to ATmega168
>   (with a 20MHz top cpu speed), the clock was left at 16MHz (probably)
>   because the designers thought that more people/code would have
>   backward compatibility issues with a new clock rate than would benefit
>   from the extra 25% cpu performance.  *I* certainly think they were
>   right...

Answer (score 7):

Actually, one of the best reasons I've heard is that the UART can perfectly match 1 Mbit and 2 Mbit rates when running at 16 MHz, but not when running at 20 MHz. There are a number of devices that have 1 and 2 Mbit UART inputs, such as the Dynamixel line of robot servos.

Answer (score 6):

A third point is that the Low Power Crystal Oscillator of the ATmega168 and ATmega328 is not working above 16 MHz. So if you have a 20 MHz crystal connected to the XTAL pins, you have to use the Full Swing Crystal Oscillator which will consume more power (or use no crystal at all).